# Laravel check variable passed from controller if not empty in view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a variable passed from my controller to my view. And I want to do a check in my view if the variable is empty I show a message if it's not empty I show a div.

This is what I've tried but it gives me a syntax error:

```
@if(!empty({!! $json !!}))
  <div class=""></div>
@else
  <p>Empty.</p>
@endif
```

I've also tried

```
@if(!empty($json))
```

Doesn't work either. I can't get to see the `empty` message

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Do `dd($json)` and see what the value actually is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type are your variable? String?

Try

```
@if( !empty( json_decode( $json) ) )
```

Comment: Okay cool this did the trick! Thanks a lot! Did not know it mattered if it's json or not :) Thanks anyways!

Comment: I don't think it does really, you just had invalid syntax.  You shouldn't use `{!! $json !!} because as soon as you use @if() everything is in PHP and PHP doesn't know how to parse `{!! !!}.  All you really needed to do is remove those.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to:

```
<?php $json = json_decode($json, true) ?>
```

somewhere before `@if` because you gets string `"[]"` not array so you need to parse json to be array. Best place is to do it in the controller.

You also don't need to escape it inside `@if` statement:

```
@if(!empty($json))
```

Comment: Try to dump it please and paste what you get

Comment: I get this from the dump `"[]"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@if(count($json) > 0)
  <div class=""></div>
@else
  <p>Empty.</p>
@endif
```